# Ansible Inventory - Use host entries in a group in a loop

Tags: ansible, ansible-inventory

Background: I have a dynamic ansible inventory that is built by a previously run process, I don't know the IPs until after this task completes. I have 2 groups: db servers and web servers defined in the inventory file. The specific task I am trying to complete is create some_user@'dynamic_ip_of_webserver_group'.

I think I am close but somethings not quite right. In my dbserver role main task I have:

```
- name: Create DB User
      mysql_user:
        name: dbuser
        host: "{{ item }}"
        password: "{{ mysql_wordpress_password }}"
        priv: "someDB.*:ALL"
      with_items:
        - "{{ ansible_hostname }}"
        - 127.0.0.1
        - ::1
        - localhost
        - "{{ hostvars[groups['webservers']] }}"
```

This errors out with:

```
TASK [dbservers : Create DB User] *******************************************************************************************************************************************************************
fatal: [10.10.10.13]: FAILED! => {"msg": "ansible.vars.hostvars.HostVars object has no element [u'10.10.10.30', u'10.10.10.240']"}
```

It is showing the right IPs and there is only 2 so both of those are correct. I think it is trying to access the inventory item as an object instead of the actual input?

Inventory File:

```
[webservers]
10.10.10.30
10.10.10.240
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply:

```
- "{{ groups['webservers'] }}"
```

<sup>This works, because `with_items` flattens first nested level of lists.</sup>